# Invalid Drive F when installing MSI installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation, setup-project, usb-flash-drive

I am encountering an INVALID DRIVE F:/ message when installing an installer that I created using VS2010 Setup Project.

[image: Dialogbox]

Drive F is not existing. We just did file transfer from a usb flash drive (:F/) previously.

Solutions we did:

SOLUTION 1:Check the Windows Installer Service.
1. Click Start Orb, in the start search box, type Services.msc and press Enter.
2. Scroll down and find the Windows Installer. Double-click “Windows Installer” in the Services list.
3. On the General tab, make sure the service is started under “Service status”.
4. If the service is not already running, under Service status, click Start, and then click OK.

SOLUTION 2: Unregister and re-register the Windows Installer
1. Click Start Orb, in the start search box, type MSIEXEC /UNREGISTER, and then click OK .
2. Click Start Orb, in the start search box, type MSIEXEC /REGSERVER, and then click OK . After you run this command, the operation is complete.
3. Now, try your installation again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Windows Installer errormessage.
It seems you have a hardcoded value in your package.
Please create a logfile during installation and you can better find the solution in this.
You can create a logfile if you use the following scheme to call the installation:

```
msiexec /i "<pathtoname.msi>" /qb /l*v "<pathtologfile.log>"
```

The logfile gives you detailed informations about your installation and a returncode at the end. This can help to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack might also be possible, start a CMD and type:

```
cd \
subst F: .
```

then try installing again.